# AngularJS ng-bind-html

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

This is my filter in Angular, I've only shown the snippet of it the application. This works in one controller but when I try to use it in another one it doesn't.

What I mean by is doesn't work - it doesnt render inside the DOM. It renders inside the tags though.

AngularJS:
`<h2 ng-bind-html="'{{ answer.title }}' | to_trusted"></h2>`

Example Rendered
`<h2 ng-bind-html="'0-60 minutes per week' | to_trusted" class="ng-binding"></h2>`

AngularJS Filter

```
    .filter('to_trusted', ['$sce', function($sce){
        return function(text) {
            return $sce.trustAsHtml(text);
        };
    }])
```

Have I missed something out by accident here?

Comment: Why are you using `''` to wrap the `{{}}` ?

Comment: @OmriAharon because I receive `Error: [$parse:syntax] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.18/$parse/syntax?p0=to_trusted&p1=is%20an%20unexpected%20token&p2=4&p3=%20%7C%20to_trusted&p4=to_trusted
    at Error (native)` Error message

Comment: I believe my answer will address the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what will make it work for you is this syntax, since `answer.title` is text already:

```
<h2 ng-bind-html="answer.title | to_trusted"></h2>
```